# Is the ideal $ (X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1) $ prime in $ \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am not very confident that what I have done is right although I can't see any flaw in it. So here it goes:

Since $ (Y^{2}+1) \subseteq  (X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1) $, by the third isomorphism theorem for rings we have that $$ \frac{\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]}{(X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1)}  \simeq \frac{(\mathbb{Q}[X])[Y]\big/(Y^{2}+1)}{(X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1)\big/(Y^{2}+1)} $$ 
Hence $$ \frac{\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]}{(X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1)}  \simeq \frac{(\mathbb{Q}[i])[X]}{(X^{2}+1)}= \frac{(\mathbb{Q}[i])[X]}{(X+i)(X-i)} $$ which by the Chinese Remainder Theorem is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Q}[i] \times \mathbb{Q}[i] $ and since clearly this is not a domain, we conclude that $ (X^{2}+1,Y^{2}+1) $ does not belong to the spectrum of $ \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] $.

I would be thankful for any comments and hints in case my solution is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is prime. Consider $Y^2(X^2+1)-X^2(Y^2+1)$. It equals $Y^2-X^2=(Y+X)(Y-X)$. Are $Y+X$ and $Y-X$ in it?

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your solution is correct, as is that of Li Li  (note: you can also simply take $Y^2+1$ and then subtract $X^2+1$,  there is no need to multiply them by $X^2$ and $Y^2$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like your proof a lot -- it's the right way to think about this ring. For a more elementary argument, note that $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ belongs to this ideal but for degree reasons, neither $x+y$ nor $x-y$ can.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and for the elementary argument!

Answer (score 5):

Very well done, I think you can skip the CRT part, since $X \pm i$ is a nontrivial zero-divisor, which is easily seen from $\frac{(\mathbb{Q}[i])[X]}{(X+i)(X-i)}$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the shortcut!